# How do I read show notes while playing a podcast in the iOS Podcasts app?

Tags: podcasts, ios, podcasts.app

I can’t figure out how to view show notes in the iOS Podcasts app.

Previously, I could just tap on the album art in the now playing screen, and it would display the show notes just like lyrics to song. But now, tapping the album art brings up a tape deck.

Where from can I read the show notes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Tap on an individual subscription or "Unplayed Episodes":**

[image]

**2. Tap on the blue disclosure indicator:**

**3. This will display the show notes for that episode:**

[image]

Comment: I have two podcasts (The CultCast and Mac OS Ken) with me right now, and none of them show the notes with this method. I will contact the makers about it. Thanks!

Comment: Those podcasts display show notes for me. I subscribed through the built-in "Catalog" in the upper-left corner of the app.

Comment: And I am syncing with iTunes, and most of the times, iTunes downloads them before my device. Strange. I’ll investigate.